# Two separate svgs are colliding

Tags: svg

I have two separate svgs as such

```
<svg>svg 1 stuff</svg>
```

then another svg

```
<svg> svg 2 stuff </svg>
```

If I render them separately it's fine. Buf if I do this

```
<svg> svg 1 stuff</svg>
<svg>svg 2 stuff</svg>
```

It seems the styles or css or something is interacting and the svgs look funny?

Isn't the styles or css within each svg independent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible there is clashing CSS.  If they are both in the same document then any CSS that are in either SVG will be applied to everything.  Later rules may override earlier ones and affect both SVGs.

What is perhaps more likely is that they have clashing `id` attributes. This is a common problem if you have used an editor program like Illustrator to create these files.  The program will automatically generate `id` attribute values for elements like gradients, masks and clipping paths.  Unfortunately they tend to generate the same sequence of ids for every new file.

`id` attributes have to be unique in a document, so if there are duplicates when you combine both SVGs in the page, then unpredictable things happen.  What exactly happens will depend on the browser. So if the file looks different in Chrome and Firefox, then that is a clue that it is duplicate `id` attributes that are the problem.

There is really no easy solution to fix the problem other than manually going through one of the SVGs and renaming the `id` attributes **and** anything that references them.